# Probability of coin flip leading the race

Tags: probability

I was recently asked this question in an interview

You keep flipping a coin and whilst you do this, you keep track of the number of heads and tails.

You can think of this as a race between heads and tails. For example if after 9 flips, you have 7 heads and 2 tails, then heads is winning the race by 5

Consider a race of 10 flips, What is the probability that if you flip Tails first, Heads will be winning the race?

My approach:

Heads must win 6 or more of the remaining 9 matches to be leading the race of 10

$$ \frac {9C6 + 9C7 + 9C8 + 1}  {2^9}  =  0.25 $$

Is this approach correct? or should the answer be 0.5 instead (which my friend claims is the ans)

Comment: In order to win the race, given that the first toss was $T$, you need at least $6$ Heads out of $9$, so just use the binomial distribution.  That gives $0.25390625$ so a bit more than $.25$  I see no argument for $.5$  ... clearly $H$ is at a serious disadvantage.

Comment: Your approach is correct, although $\ 0.25\ $ is only  an approximation to the exact value of the probability, which is  $\ \frac{65}{256}=0.25390625\ .$

Comment: To stress, even before the first toss, the answer was $<.5$ since (I'm guessing) ties don't count as wins for $H$.  (if ties do count as wins for $H$, then the answer is $>.5$).